# azure devops pipeline can't find files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following simple pipeline that I'd like to run a bicep file with param file:

```
name: "BRCi.HMRC.Scaffolding"
trigger: none
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
stages:
  - stage: DeployTest
    variables:
      env: Test
    jobs:
      - deployment: deploy
        environment: Test
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: CmdLine@2
                  displayName: List files2
                  inputs:
                    script: |
                      echo "Structure of work folder of this pipeline:"
                      tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) 
                - task: AzureCLI@2
                  displayName: Deploy Template
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: brci-devops-sc-tst-BRCi.HMRC
                    scriptType: pscore
                    scriptLocation: inlineScript
                    inlineScript: az deployment group create `
                      --resource-group brci-hmrc2-rg-tst
                      --template-file $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Bicep/Main.bicep `
                      --parameters $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Bicep/Hmrc.Parameters.Test.json
```

The output from the List files2 job looks good:

```
/home/vsts/work/1 
├── TestResults 
├── a 
├── b 
└── s 
├── Bicep 
│   ├── Hmrc.Parameters.Test.json 
│   ├── Main.bicep 
│   └── giftaidLogicApp.bicep 
├── README.md 
└── azure-pipelines.yml
```

But, the line that tries to run az deployment group create fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: An error occurred reading file. Could not find a part of the path '/home/vsts/work/1/Bicep/Main.bicep'.
```

Comment: Hi Rob Bowman; just checking if I've understood that Tree output correctly. Is the Bicep folder under 's', or is it under '1' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please set workingDirectory as `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` for your `task: AzureCLI@2`

I ran this:

```yaml
- deployment: DeployWeb
  displayName: deploy Web App
  environment: 'Dev'
  strategy: 
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self
        - script: |
            pwd
            echo "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
```

and got

```
/home/vsts/work/1/s
/home/vsts/work/1
```

So your task is executed in `/home/vsts/work/1/s` and this is why you need to switch workingDirectory.